# GRUB не отображается на компьютере с UEFI

Tags: linux, grub, uefi

Всем доброго времени суток!
Есть комп с UEFI и предустановленной Windows 7. 
Установлена Linux из-под live-usb (разделы размечены автоматом, gpt).
В итоге загрузчик grub отображается только при подключении live-usb в режиме 'Security Boot - Enabled' и только как командная строка. Раздел с Linux из-под стандартного загрузчика, конечно, не виден (только usb, lan, hdd с Windows), и как загрузиться с него - непонятно.
Были попробованы разные варианты решения, как, например, из-под терминала на live-usb:

```
$ sudo mount /dev/sda6 /mnt
$ sudo grub-install —root-directory=/mnt /dev/sda
$ sudo update-grub
```

А также из-под терминала grub2:

```
$ set root=(hd1,gpt6)
$ linux (hd1,gpt6)/boot/vmlinuz-3.<...>-generic root=/dev/sda6
$ initrd (hd1,gpt6)/boot/initrd.img-3.<...>-generic
$ boot
```

Однако к желаемому результату (отображению grub'а в виде списка ОСей и без подключения флэшки) они не привели.
Что посоветуете еще попробовать предпринять?

Comment: я насчитал как минимум три разных проблемы в вашем вопросе. конкретизируйте, пожалуйста, свой вопрос до **одной** проблемы. внести исправления можно, нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса.

Comment: Проблема одна - grub не отображается без подключения live-usb, UEFI не видит его директорию на компе. Все прочие проблемы вызваны попытками решить изначальную.

Comment: тогда уберите, пожалуйста, из вопроса всю лишнюю информацию. про всякие initramfs, startx и т.п.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Все оказалось просто: для того, чтобы grub2 благополучно установился, необходимо выставить перед установкой Linux 'UEFI only'-mode.